# Does $f^{-1}(B)\subset A \iff B\subset f(A)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

$f$ is a function. Does $f^{-1}(B)\subset A \iff B\subset f(A)$? If yes, is this true for a mapping? If not, is this true in one direction? (This comes from proving a function is measurable iff it's measurable on the generator of the range-sigma algebra)

Comment: $\Leftarrow$ is not true in general, unless $f$ is injective.

Comment: Why the [tag:measure-theory], [tag:general-topology] tag?

Comment: Can you give a reference @ryagami

Comment: @user170039 edited

Comment: A simple counter-example would be $f:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{0\}$, $f(x)=0$ with $A=\{0\}\subseteq\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{0\}\subseteq\{0\}$.

Answer (score 4):

No, for $f : X\rightarrow Y$ you do not even have 
$$
f^{-1}(B)\subset A \Longrightarrow B\subset f(A)
$$
because in the left hand side $B\subset Y$ and can be $Y$ itself.

A counterexample is as follows 
$$
X=Y=A=B=\{0,1\},\ f(0)=f(1)=0\ .
$$
For a counterexample on the the other direction (converse implication $\Longleftarrow$), take $B=\{0\}$ and $A=\{1\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Mariano for catching my egregious mistakes.

Take $f(x) = \sin x$, and $A=[0,2\pi)$, $B =[-1,1]$, then
$B \subset f(A)$ but $f^{-1}(B) = \mathbb{R}$.

For the other direction, take $B = \{2\}$, then $f^{-1}(B) = \emptyset \subset A$, but $B \not\subset f(A) = [-1,1]$.

Comment: What happens if B is not empty and it is disjoint to the image of f?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Notice that it is still not true that $B$ is contained in $f(A)$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: More thanks.

Comment: :-) ${}{}{}{}{}$